# Popover View is Blank

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I am trying to add a popover to my controller using code. For some reason, the popover appears, but there is no content inside.

[image]

The code I'm using for the transition is:

```
@IBAction func presentPopover(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //performSegueWithIdentifier("Popover", sender: self)
    let vc = PopoverViewController()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = .right
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    ...
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The popover view is made in the storyboard, and is of class `PopoverViewController` After doing some testing it says that the `PopoverViewController's` `viewDidAppear` is triggered.

[image]

Comment: The line `let vc = PopoverViewController()` does not use the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) mention The line let `vc = PopoverViewController()` does not use the storyboard. so you need to do it like that

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverViewController") as? PopoverViewController {
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = .right
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds                        
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to post that the comment was helpful @rmaddy. Thanks for bundling it up in a nice concise answer

Comment: This code is incorrect. There is no "AnotherViewController". You need to load the PopoverViewController` from the storyboard. And this code declares a 2nd `vc` variable inside the `if let`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for pointing out i have taking my sample code for my `AnotherViewController` and edited for questions so that second `vc variable` left there. I have edited answer.